# Reflection: If PropertyInfo implements ICollection

Tags: c#, reflection, icollection

I am using reflection to loop through the properties of an array of objects of type Dynamic.

I am looping through the PropertyInfos, and want to know if the type is implementing an ICollection, but I don't want to define what the collection is, just that it is an ICollection.

What is the syntax to achieve this?

code below:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in Item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (propertyInfo is ICollection<>)
            {

            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: THOSE DONT WORK, I ALREADY READ THEM, THATS WHY I POSTED.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example